# Python creates the csv but its empty

Tags: python, csv

I finally got it to create the csv file but for some reason it creates the headers but never fills in the data

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = "http://www.scsotx.org/jail-booking"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

inmate_data =[]

table = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class':'sex-offender-info'})

for row in table.findAll('div', attrs = {'class':'jail-content'}):
    jaildata = {}
    jaildata['Name'] = row.h4.text
    jaildata['Agency'] = row.p.text
    inmate_data.append(jail-content)


with open('C:\\Users\Cale\Desktop\jail\inmate_data.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,['Name','Agency'])
    w.writeheader()
    for jaildata in inmate_data:
        w.writerow(jaildata)
```

its supposed to parse the html data and then append the csv file

Answer (score 2):

Here's your code fixed:

```
for row in table.findAll("figcaption", attrs={"class": "jail-content"}):
    jaildata = {}
    jaildata["Name"] = row.h4.text
    jaildata["Agency"] = row.p.text
    inmate_data.append(jaildata)
```

The data you were looking for was inside `<figcaption>` instead of `<div>`, and also there was a typo with `jail-content` instead of `jaildata` when trying to append.

Comment: Please add an explanation on where the mistake was.

Comment: I've added a brief explanation of the two mistakes.

Comment: thank you the typo was so stupid to miss but the figcaption makes sense, any idea why it still only returns the one result? should i use findAll in the table?

Comment: changed     table = soup.find("body")

Answer (score 0):

Although I strongly recommend you to use selenium for this sort of thing, this is what you can do to improve the workings of your **scraping**:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class ScrapeJail:
    def __init__(self, url: str = "http://www.scsotx.org/jail-booking"):
        self.url = url

    def get_table(self):
        response = requests.get(self.url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')
        raw_data = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'sex-off-box'})
        data_contents = raw_data.findAll('div', attrs={'class': "medium-4 small-6 columns"})
        data = []
        for i, _ in enumerate(data_contents):
            person_data_tags = data_contents[i].findAll('div', attrs={'class': "sex-offender-info"})
            person_data_jail = person_data_tags[0].findAll(attrs={'class': "jail-content"})
            person_data = person_data_jail[0].findChildren()
            person_dict = {}
            for tag in person_data:
                person_text = tag.text
                try:
                    points = person_text.index(':')
                    person_dict[person_text[:points]] = person_text[points + 1:]
                    data.append(person_dict)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
        return data

    def data_frame(self):
        return pd.DataFrame(self.get_table())

    def export_csv(self, file_name:str):
        df = self.data_frame()
        df.to_csv(file_name)
```

Not perfect, the charges are not perfect, but simply do a

```
data = ScrapeJail()

csv = data.export_csv('file_name.csv')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for row in table.findAll('div', attrs = {'class':'jail-content'}):
jaildata = {}
jaildata['Name'] = row.h4.text
jaildata['Agency'] = row.p.text
inmate_data.append(jail-content)
```

If you look at this block, the variable `jail-content` on the last line isn't being declared at all. I'm assuming you want to use `jaildata`?

Comment: thanks for catching the typo guys. the figcaption change fixed that part but something is still wrong its not going through the whole page only returns the one result